# Creating task in Asana

Tags: asana

Hi Guys I am trying to create task using the Asana Api but somehow am getting error. The json that i used to create task is

```
{
           "data":{
         "assignee":{
         "id":1259201588185,
         "name":"Test User"
          },
          "assignee_status":"upcoming",
          "completed":false,
          "due_on":null,
          "name":"testing",
          "notes":"testing",
          "projects":[

          ],
          "workspace":{
         "id":1259201588293,
         "name":"TestSpace"
          }
       }
    }
```

but whenever I am trying to post the same I am getting error "message":"Invalid field" with the above json

Comment: use https://github.com/acron0/AsanaNet

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana)

Make sure you are setting the header `Content-Type: application/json` in the request so the server knows to look for your data in that format.